# NSURLConnection with different DNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Unfortunately, in our country, YouTube ([Youtube](http://youtube.com) or [Gdata.youtube](http://gdata.youtube.com)) has been banned by the government. So we can't access the services without changing the DNS or using a VPN.

I need to use `NSURLConnection` to pull data from `gdata.youtube`.

Is it possible to change the DNS programmatically? Or, is there any other way of accessing the site?

Comment: by "disability access" you mean that it is disabled, right? "disability access" means that disabled people can also access it, if that term even exists. I don't understand "a time youtube has disability access"

Comment: VPN / proxy based solution. You can't change the device DNS AFAIK

Comment: @Michael Yes it's been banned.

Comment: Use this to bypass the blockade https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/onavo-extend-data-usage-get/id423545287?mt=8 I don't think it's a good idea to mess with network settings in the app even if it's possible.

Comment: @Desdenova When I change the DNS address of the device can go on YouTube. but of all the users of the program can not ask you to do this.

Comment: @user2041226 Bu senin problemin değil. Ne zaman açtılar, ne zaman kapadılar, takibini de yapamazsın ki uygulamayı öne göre değiştirebilesin. / This is not your problem. You can't keep track of the ban to update the app accordingly.

Comment: @Desdenova yani tib engeli kaldırmadan youtube erişme şansımız yok doğrumu anladım? / tib so we do not have any chance of going to YouTube from unblocking I understood correctly?

Comment: @user2041226 Kısmen, kullanıcılar cihazlarına VPN kurarak erişebilirler fakat bu bizi ilgilendirmiyor. Sanki normal erişim varmış gibi uygulamayı yapıp kullanıcıya sunuyoruz, yasağı nasıl aştıkları onların problemi. / Partially. Users can access those services with VPN but that is not our concern. We develop the app and serve to users assuming we have regular access. How they bypass the ban is their problem.